# Undergrad grades in PhD

Tags: phd, grades

For someone who has just finished his M.Sc. with extremely good grades, is it possible that their not so extremely good grades during undergrad might affect where they get their PhD?

Comment: Which country for the undergrad/MSc/PhD?

Comment: India is my country

Comment: And you are looking for a PhD in India?  (And please update the question accordingly!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not provided enough details in your question I will go with a generalised answer to this end. The answer to this question, however, is country- and organisation-specific. Further, it does also depends on the PhD advisor herself.

I am in academics for a few years now and I have seen some post-grads (not PhD) who do/did have bad grades during their corresponding undergraduate studies.

First, let's quantify what does a bad grade mean: On a scale of 1-10 (10 being the highest), bad grade would be, according to me somewhere within 4. "Ok" grades would be the ones falling in the range: 5-7, and above 7 is just great. As I said, this can be argued; but lets for the moment accept these as axioms.

So, if your grades in the "bad" category, then you should have something additional to show to the PhD selection committee or the advisor you are applying under. This term "extra" would mean something like a voluntary project that you did, maybe a collaborative work you participated in, or an article that you wrote with some others. Again, this extra stuff that you show may not be well-accepted but would definitely provide a soft edge towards the decision-making process. Also, note that PhD application might require a few recommendation letters if those letters could mention these extras to compensate for your bad grades, then you are okay I think.

If you have nothing to show as an extra component, then this might not be a good sign to have "bad" grades in the CV. A PhD position would expect someone to be serious in studies and highly motivated to pursue research.

Comment: My grades in undergrad are around 9/10. And I am wishing for a Ph.D. in Physics. Isn't 9/10 not too good for a physics degree?

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar Is 9/10 considered low in your university? What percentile does it place you in? Grading scales can vary a lot, so just the number may not be very meaningful. In some places, 9/10 would put you in the top 5-10% of the class.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes, you are right. 9/10 could put you in top 5 %ile. But, I think it is still a pretty good score to get filtered in the application process.

Comment: Ah, you are safe. Just enjoy :-) @SarthakGirdhar

Comment: Care to explain negative vote please?

Comment: It's not me who has voted negatively on the answer.  I find it weird too.

Answer (score 0):

Depends - but I feel if you can convincingly communicate why you want the PhD position you are applying for, I doubt your undergrad grades are going to be detrimental.

Also, I recon this differs a lot from country to country and field of research.

Comment: I am from India and here we are veryyyy marks oriented.

Comment: What is the meaning of "marks oriented"? Why is this answer negatively voted?

Comment: @coder marks oriented means here we are obsessed with grades. Your high school grades, your rank, your GPA define you to a large extent.